# how to use SavedModelBuilder to export a nlp model

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-serving

I trained a **nmt** model and I want to export the model and deploy it on tensorflow serving. But I have some problems that confused me a few days:

- The trained model contains all the info that **SavedModelBuilder** needs, including meta graph and variables, so why should we create a signature for the builder? Can we just specified the model directory and the builder finishes rest of the works?
- What should I do if I want to export the model? I read the tutorial of exporting a **MNIST** model, but the **MNIST** demo is different with my **nmt** demo, so I still not understand how to create the signature exactly. Is there any example that shows how to export a nlp model?

Comment: Hard to say exactly how to export your NMT model without more detail. If there's a TensorFlow model example that's close to it, you could file a feature request for a saved_model export example. Or if you have a specific API question, you could include that here.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I tried to export my model with this code [export nmt trained model](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/712), but it does't work. Can you figure out which step was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2018-05-30

This answer is wrong!
I found the wright way to export the model, and works well with tf serving.
Visit my fork of `tensorflow/nmt` at [tensorflow/nmt](https://github.com/luozhouyang/nmt), or go to the pull request: [pull request#344](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/pull/344)

### Wrong answer

I found the way to export the model!
Here is my code:

```
    if not self.model_dir:
        raise ValueError("Please specified a model dir.")
    export_path = os.path.join(
        tf.compat.as_bytes(self.export_base_path),
        tf.compat.as_bytes(str(self.version_number))
    )

    config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
    sess = tf.Session(config=config)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(self.model_dir, "translate.ckpt-21000.meta"))
    latest_ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(self.model_dir)
    saver.restore(sess, latest_ckpt)

    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

    feature_configs = {
        'x': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.string),
        'y': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
    }
    serialized_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name="tf_example")
    tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_example, feature_configs)
    x = tf.identity(tf_example['x'], name='x')
    y = tf.identity(tf_example['y'], name='y')
    # predict_input = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(x)
    # predict_output = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(y)
    predict_input = x
    predict_output = y
    predict_signature_def_map = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
        inputs={
            tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_INPUTS: predict_input
        },
        outputs={
            tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_OUTPUTS: predict_output
        }
    )

    legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name="legacy_init_op")
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        sess=sess,
        tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        signature_def_map={
            "predict_signature_map": predict_signature_def_map
        },
        legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op,
        assets_collection=None
    )
    builder.save()
```

The directory of my export model looks like:

```
|----1
    |----saved_model.pb
    |----variables
        |----variables.data-00000-of-00002
        |----variables.data-00001-of-00002
        |----varaibles.index
```

Comment: Hi, I can export the model fine using the code you posted. Thanks very much. Do you also have any client code? I tried adapting the Inception/MNIST examples but get error "input size does not match signature", not sure what the size should be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why signatures: the graph otherwise doesn't indicate what's an input and what's an output, and this information is needed for serving (it's provided implicitly when you load a graph in a Python program and do something with it; for serving it needs to be explicit).

I would take a look at [simple_save](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/simple_save.py) for a nicer API to create saved models, although I don't think it's made it into a TensorFlow release yet (for now you could copy those few lines as boilerplate).

Answer (score 0):

Good news! I make it! I exported the model successfully, and served it by tf serving, it works well!

Created a module `exporter.py` to export pre-trained model, and add a few extra arguments in `nmt.py` module which are needed for exporting.
For testing exporter, I trained a simple model using test datas from the `nmt/testdata/` folder, and saved the model in `nmt/testdata/models`. After this, run the test of exporter, it will generate a new folder named export in `nmt/testdata/models`, which is what we expected and can be served by tf serving.

You can visit the pull request [pull request#344](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/pull/344)
 or go to my fork directly [tensorflow/nmt](https://github.com/luozhouyang/nmt)

Comment: Recommend you at-least put a summary of the code's solution